# Encoding an Html helper written to the screen via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, encoding

I'm wanting to add an element created using an Html helper to the screen via Javascript like so:

```
var element = '<%: Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Item) %>';
$('body').append(element)
```

How do I then properly encode this element so it's safe but also writes the html to the screen?

Comment: Ew. Don't mix the MVC together with JavaScript like that. Write JSON to your javascript and use a javascript view/rendering system if can't work with the existing MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extremely ugly but it might work:

```
var element = '<%= Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Item).ToHtmlString() %>';
$('body').append(element);
```

and if you want to ensure proper encoding:

```
var element = '<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Item).ToHtmlString()) %>';
$('body').append(element);
```

A better solution:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<input/>', {
        name: 'Item',
        value: '<%= Model.Item %>'
    })
);
```

Comment: It worked! In fact, it also worked using <%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Partial(...).ToHtmlString()) %>